# Save PayPal Vault in Braintree without any Transaction

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I have following Problem - Btw. I can't find any solutions in the offical braintree documentation.

I build a demo app, this app has the PayPal Vault integration. My Problem is now, how to handle the paymentNonce on the Server Side Implementation. Because to save the payment-method in the vault, it is necessary to do a transaction.

In my future App, I will save the payment-method with the vault flow, while the registration and will use that for my further payments. Can anyone tell me, what I must do to save the payment-method in the vault without a transaction?

Edit: I need a solution for the Java Braintree SDK

Comment: See the documentation at https://graphql.braintreepayments.com/guides/vaulting_payment_methods/

Comment: Yes thanks, but i don´t know how to use that with the Braintree SDK in Java. Sorry i forgot this in my Question

Comment: Hey Marcel, the link above has GraphQL, not Java. You still having trouble with this?

Comment: Hey @0xtobit thanks for the response. No I don't have any problems there. But if you want I can share my solution.

Comment: All good Marcel! Just wanted to make sure you were helped 